# How did the two strange people also get to know about the Beatles music?

Tags: plot-explanation, yesterday

In the movie ***Yesterday (2019)***, we see that except Jack Malik,

> nobody knew that The Beatles band existed

How come there were two other people who also shared this? and appear randomly in his shows and confess in the last part of the movie that they want the legend to live forever. Are we to understand that those two also emerged back from the global blackout with the knowledge of the band?

Comment: Is there any reason you *don't* think we are to believe it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: at least 3 people (Jack Malik and the two strangers) remember the Beatles. Everyone else is in an alternate timeline in which John, Paul, George, and Ringo never formed The Beatles and never wrote any of the songs that Jack Malik remembers.

Comment: I think that OP doesn't want to know if it's true, but want to know how it is possible.

Comment: @TinyDoowy The OP's question that stood out to me is the last one: "Are we to understand that those two also emerged back from the global blackout with the knowledge of the band?" And the movie shows that the answer is "yes". As for _how_ it was possible: the movie never explains the phenomenon or the mechanics of the phenomenon, so I think it could easily happen to multiple people. The screenwriter might not even have it all figured out; the script doesn't focus much on science or logic.